# Массовое копирование названия классов из HTML в CSS

Tags: html, css, frontend, sublime-text, webstorm

В редакторе сублайм текст есть очень крутой плагин Tag, позволяющий скопировать все имена классов из тэгов HTML в стили CSS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли, сделать тоже самое в иде WebStorm?

Comment: попробуйте плагин ECSStractor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такой возможности нет. Проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-338](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-338).

Я могу только порекомендовать использовать **Create selector** quickfix для классов в HTML (доступен по `Alt+Enter`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]